# Unity multiplayer game with socket is working for mobile devices?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sockets, websocket, multiplayer

I am developing a Multiplayer game with the help of Unity and Socket. But somehow my project running well and connecting to the server but when I make an Android build it's not connecting to the server.

I have used https://github.com/itisnajim/SocketIOUnity for the socket connection.

Is there any setting for mobile devices so I can check on the mobile devices?

Is there any third party package is available to make it happen? Connecting unity app with socket to the server?

Thanks

Comment: not an android person but dont you need to ask app permissions?

Comment: Check logcat for errors. I think you'll find your problem there.

Comment: logcat is not showing any kind of errors

Comment: I don't find any permission to ask for socket connections.

Comment: btw why do you need the 3rd party package? what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: I am making multiplayer game and whats to pass data to each other players who are plaing the game in same room. now when I run game with editor it's connecting to server and passing datas to each other but when I try to run same project in simmulator or android devices it's not even connecting to server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.